# How can I access constructor 'this' inside Ramda?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

Whenever I try to access any `this` inside Ramda Compose function (`R.compose`) I get `undefined`, maybe it's because `this` is 'binded' to the Ramda Compose function.

How can I make `this` access something that is initiated in the `Class` constructor?

`this.state` is undefined inside `getContent` in the code below:

```
export default class FaqStore {
  constructor() {
    this.state = new FaqState()

    this.getParents()
  }

  getContent = R.concat(this.state.parents, R.prop('content'))
  getParents = FaqService.getParents().then(this.getContent)
```

Comment: What syntax is this? The code is incomplete and doesn't look like ES6. If you are using the public class properties proposal, then `R.concat(this.state.parents, R.prop('content'))` is likely evaluated before you set `this.state`. Solution: Move the `getContent` and `getParents` assignment into the constructor, after you assign `this.state`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are using the public class fields proposals. Properties created this way are [evaluated before the constructor itself is executed](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/#[[construct]]) (step 8 and 11).

I.e. your code is equivalent to

```
export default class FaqStore {
  constructor() {
    this.getContent = R.concat(this.state.parents, R.prop('content'))
    this.getParents = FaqService.getParents().then(this.getContent)

    this.state = new FaqState()

    this.getParents()
  }
}
```

This clearly shows that you are trying to access `this.state` before it was initialized.

**Possible Solution**

Don't use the proposal and set the properties directly in the constructor, *after* you initialized `this.state`:

```
export default class FaqStore {
  constructor() {
    this.state = new FaqState()

    this.getContent = R.concat(this.state.parents, R.prop('content'))
    this.getParents = FaqService.getParents().then(this.getContent)

    this.getParents()
  }
}
```

---

**However**, there is still an issue: The value assigned to `getParents` is a promise. You cannot *call* a promise (`this.getParents()`). Maybe what you really want is to assign a function to `getParents`:

```
this.getParents = () => FaqService.getParents().then(this.getContent)
```

And maybe `R.concat` doesn't return a function either, in which case `this.getContent` cannot be called either. In that case, what you actually want is

```
export default class FaqStore {
  constructor() {
    this.state = new FaqState()

    this.getParents()
  }

  getContent = () => R.concat(this.state.parents, R.prop('content'))
  getParents = () => FaqService.getParents().then(this.getContent)
}
```

i.e. assign *functions* to `getContent` and `getParents`.

Comment: [`R.concat(…, …)`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#concat) *certainly* does not return a function :-) I guess OP meant `R.compose(R.concat(this.state.parents), R.prop('content'))`

Answer (score 5):

The answer from Felix Kling is excellent.  I want to add a little more context from Ramda, though.

Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors) is about functional programming.  It tries to do two things: to make it easier for Javascript developers to move towards more standard FP practices, and to make it easier for users of FP languages to work with Javascript.  There is no emphasis at all on interoperating with object-oriented styles of coding.

At one point Ramda did try to ensure that certain of its functions did maintain the `this` context, which would allow them to be used as OOP methods.  But we are dropping this focus entirely; it had always been speculative, without any requests at all for it, and when we accidentally broke it for some functions, we had no complaints at all.  There seems to be little reason for it.  Meanwhile it complicates our implementation and hurts performance.  So as we find the need to rewrite functions, we're no longer trying to ensure that this is maintained.

This makes sense.  Some people see Ramda as an alternative to Underscore or lodash, but that has always seemed skewed to us.  Those libraries introduce some FP concepts, but they're designed to work in multi-paradigm environments, equally happy with imperative, OOP, or FP codebases.  Ramda is different, designed to work well only in functional systems.  It's built entirely around the notion of building systems by composing pure functions.

For these reasons, on top of everything Felix said, there's no real reason to expect that a Ramda function will maintain your `this` context.